# Django messages refuse to display

Tags: python, django, message

I've been trying to display an alert for whenever a user posts an invalid comment on my site (such as a blank post). I decided to use the messages framework, however it doesn't seem to work. I've made sure that the app, middleware, and template context processors were correct, and that my views were using a RequestContext object. If I use `{% debug %}` in my template, I can see the "messages" variable set, but with nothing in there.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS =  ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)
```

**views.py**

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    uid = request.session.get('uid', 0);
    q = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id);

    context = RequestContext(request, {'question': q, 'uid':uid});
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context_instance=context);

def post_comment(request, question_id):
    try:
        if (request.POST['comment_text'] == ""):
            messages.error(request, "Cannot submit an empty comment!");
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={'question_id': question_id}));
        else:
            comment = Comment(
                question = Question.objects.get(id=question_id),
                submitter = request.session['uid'],
                text = sanitizer.clean(request.POST['comment_text'])
                );

            comment.save();

    except Exception, e:
        raise e;
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={'question_id': question_id}));
```

**detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for m in messages %}
    <li{% if m.tags %} class="{{ m.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ m }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Just to make sure it's set up right, did you try setting up a simple view which sets a message and renders a template to display the message, without any conditional blocks or anything? Have you used a debugger (or even just print statements) to be sure you're hitting the `messages.error(request, "Cannot submit an empty comment!");` line?

Comment: I've tried without anything, still doesn't work. And yes, I do hit the `messages.error` line.

Comment: By default, messages will use cookies as a storage backend. Is there anything with your site that may be affecting that? Have you tried setting `MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'` just to see if that changes anything?

Comment: I could've sworn the docs said the default was Session. Oh Well. Your fix worked perfectly. Can you please resubmitted your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `messages` will use the `storage.fallback.FallbackStorage` storage backend, which "first uses CookieStorage, and falls back to using SessionStorage for the messages that could not fit in a single cookie". So effectively, it uses cookies as a storage backend. If there is anything with your site that may be affecting that, you can try setting it to use sessions specifically:

```
 MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, you literally helped me. The answer is crisp and correct